# Why I cannot write `List<T> l = new List<T>();` in Java?

Tags: java, list

I can type

```
ArrayList<T> l = new ArrayListList<T>();
```

and

```
List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
```

but Java does not allow me to use

```
List<T> l = new List<T>();
```

Why?

Comment: Because `List` is an interface

Comment: `List` is an interface. You cannot instantiate an interface. `ArrayList` is a class, which is an implementation of `List`. Classes can be instantiated.

Comment: You may want to read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).  It's about abstract classes, but a lot of it applies to interfaces also.

Answer (score 2):

`List` is an interface, and so it has no method implementations and cannot be instantiated.  Your first two examples instantiate an `ArrayList`, which is a non-abstract class which implements the `List` interface.